# Service not being Started, Object not being notified

Tags: android, object, service, concurrency

I am using the code

```
Someactivity

Intent Service = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service.class);
startService(Service);
try{
    synchronized (populateAlbumList_Running) {
        populateAlbumList_Running.wait();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and i am calling Someactivity.populateAlbumList_Running.Notify() from the service

but the problem is the service is not even being started
and i am getting app not responding forever
but if i remove the wait() and start the service its working properly please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are started in the main thread. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process.

Therefore, if you `wait()` on the main thread, they won't have a chance to start. You should run this code from a background thread instead.

Comment: How can i make a service run on a different thread other than the main thread?

Comment: @SaiTeja The best option is probably to use an `IntentService`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html